# Running a geoprocessing service on selected data in ArcGIS web appbuilder

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am looking to run a geoprocessing service on a selected subset of feature data in a web app. I can use the entire feature layer as a parameter, but cannot seem to use only features selected either on the map or in the data table.

The end goal is to select one or more parcels in the web app and run a tool on only the selected features. I have tried using both the feature service and the map service as an input.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to using the interactive drawing input and running a spatial join?

Comment: Can you post the url for the gp service you're wanting to use?

Comment: I don't think my boss would be too happy about pointing anyone outside to our servers just yet, so I shouldn't. The first step is simply running a buffer around the (hopefully) selected polygons, though.

Comment: Assuming it takes a `GPFeatureRecordSetLayer`, you could create a `FeatureSet` and populate it using the array of features returned by [FeatureLayer.GetSelectedFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#getselectedfeatures).

Comment: This works with Esri's sample [Viewshed gp service](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/GPServer/Viewshed).

Comment: This certainly looks like it will work, though I am pretty much a complete novice at JavaScript. I will play around with it until I figure something out.

Comment: Do I need to write an entire widget in JavaScript to make this work? I apparently have no idea what I'm doing.

Can you post your example of getting the Viewshed gp service to accept the selected feature?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still needs help with this, the newest version of Web App Builder now comes with a Select Widget where you can pass selected features info to other widgets like a Geoprocessing widget. More information about the Select widget here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-select.htm